# Undefined function called within another function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple script which calls a function that is set in the function that the call is made...

But i get an "undefined function" error.

My script is:

```
function messages_document(messages){
    messages = JSON.parse(messages);

    function del_msg(id){
        result = call_file('del.php',id);
        if(result){
            messages[id].length = 0;
        }
    }

    var output = [];
    output.push('<p align="center"><b><u>My Messages</u></b></p> <br/><br/>');

    for(var id in messages){
        output.push('<a href="#" onclick="del_msg('+id+')">Delete Message</a>');
    }

    document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = (output.join(''));
}
```

I'm curious if i have misunderstood how scope works because i get:

> del_msg is not defined

Any ideas why this is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function statements are defined in the current scope, not globally. In this case, that means that `del_msg` exists only within the scope of `messages_document`.  However, you invoke it via an `onclick` attribute: these attributes are evaluated globally. Since `del_msg` doesn't exist globally, it doesn't work.

You have two options. One is to make `del_msg` global, by defining it outside any other functions. However, this pollutes the global namespace, generally a bad thing. Better would be to apply it to your `a` element within the scope. This is going to require building the elements via DOM methods, rather than by HTML

```
var para = document.createElement('p'),
    id,
    link;
para.innerHTML = '<b><u>My Messages</u></b></p> <br/><br/>';
para.align = 'center';

for(id in messages){
    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = '';
    link.onclick = del_msg;
    link.innerHTML = "Delete message";
    para.appendChild(link );
}

document.getElementById('main').appendChild(para);
```

Comment: Well at least i now see a nice benefit to use DOM over innerHTML :) !

Comment: Is this the best way - i've not used DOM methods before.. i intend to add more than just a click (divs and text etc) to this..

Comment: There are other ways of handling this, such as with event delegation. The best technique will rather depend on what you are actually doing.

Comment: Trying to create a inbox and the link is to "delete the message" im not following how i add the rest of the inner html data like message text etc

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the link content. Now altered.

Comment: what about adding paragraphs of text & div elements ?

Comment: @Dave You'll need to use DocumentFragments. I suggest you open a new question if you want to find out more about this: comments aren't a place for discussion.

Answer (score 4):

You have a problem with the scope in that "del_msg" is defined: You need that function to be in the global scope, but you're creating it inside a function "messages_document" (that has its own scope).

Comment: Well thats why im confused because im calling it in the messages_document function .. so surely it should be set if its also created in that function ? @Niko

Comment: @Dave - Nope, It has to be gloabal, is it that big of a problem to just move it?

Comment: No - just it seems to have different scope rules to how i learnt PHP

Comment: You're attaching it as an event handler to the `<a>` element - so when the user actually clicks that link, the function gets executed from a different context. Put `window.del_msg = del_msg;` at the end of "messages_document" for a quick & (very) dirty fix.

Comment: Ohh i see - so because im calling it like that its looking for it "outside" of the function it was called in

Comment: Making the function global is the quick, rather than good, fix to this problem, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring it like

```
var del_msg = function(id)...
```

---

Sorry confused. you are using the function on the window scope do declare it out of the other function.

The function is called with the onclick global scope.

What you have to understand here is that you are creating html code, but the onclick will be called when user click and not when you vreate the html.